# Display form selection in div in React

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reactjs

I am trying to create a UI that updates as the client selects an option from a dropdown menu. I've tried to set this up as follows: A react Parent (`App`) that renders two child components (`Inputs` and `Display`). `Inputs` renders a dropdown menu form. `Display` renders html output that displays the selection made in `Input`.

Example below:

```
    var Inputs=React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {value: 'cat'}
    },
    handleChange: function() {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value})
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <select value={this.state.value}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}>
                        <option value='cat'> Cat </option>
                        <option value='dog'> Dog </option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
})

var Display=React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <b> {this.props.l1} </b>
            </div>
        )
    }
})

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Inputs ref="inputs" />
                <Display l1={this.refs.inputs.state.value} />
            </div>
        )
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(
<App />,
document.getElementById('app')
  );
```

I expect the value to change when the client selects a new value from the dropdown.

More fundamentally, I think I'm misunderstanding how states and properties are passed in React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you want both of the components to render data based on selections you should let the App do the state management and pass data as props to each one.

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {value: 'cat'};
    },
    handleChange: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({value: e.target.value});
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Inputs value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <Display l1={this.state.value} />
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var Inputs = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <select value={this.props.value}
                        onChange={this.props.onChange}>
                        <option value='cat'> Cat </option>
                        <option value='dog'> Dog </option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```